# Morris.bar function is not recognized

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I'm trying to get a simple test page with a working Bar Graph using Morris. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Morris Test</title>
        <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
        <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                Morris.bar({
                    element: "bar",
                    data: [
                        {"x": 1, "y": 5},
                        {"x": 2, "y": 10},
                        {"x": 3, "y": 15}
                    ],
                    xkey: "x",
                    ykeys: ["y"],
                    labels: ["my graph"]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this page I get the error `TypeError: Morris.bar is not a function`. I've doubled checked that the path for Morris.min.js and Raphael.min.js are correct and I can't think of another reason that the function wouldn't be working.

Comment: what if you move your inline script in the body ?

Comment: Try a triple check then. Use your console or view source-code and open the JS file-path and check.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct syntax, use

```
Morris.Bar({ ... });
```

instead of `Morris.bar`